# subclass of UITextView not editable

Tags: ios, uitextview

I create a class named SWTextView and it inherits from UITextView. It does nothing but add a placeholder label. When I initialize a SWTextView and put it in a UITableViewCell, it's not editable even when the editable property of the SWTextView is YES. Does anyone have met the same problem?

The SWTextView is as follow:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SWTextView : UITextView

- (void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder;

@end

@interface SWTextView ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *placeholderLabel;

@end

@implementation SWTextView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _placeholderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _placeholderLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self addSubview:_placeholderLabel];

        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    [super setFont:font];
    _placeholderLabel.font = font;
}

- (void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder
{
    _placeholderLabel.text = placeholder;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [_placeholderLabel sizeToFit];
}

@end
```

Comment: Show us the code of that class please.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed hi, I have add the code in the question.

Comment: ME! did you find the solution?